# Virtualenv for a project with multiple modules

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I am trying to build a project from scratch in python 2, it has structure shown below. In past I have created projects with a single hierarchy, so there would be single `virtualenv`, but this project has multiple subpackages, what is the best practice to be followed: there should be a single virtualenv inside project_root directory shared by all subpackages in it, or there should be separate `virtualenv` for each subpackage?

```
project_root/
├── commons
│   ├── hql_helper.py
│   ├── hql_helper.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sample_HQL.hql
├── fl_wtchr
│   ├── fl_wtchr_test.py
│   ├── fl_wtchr_test.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── meta_table.hql
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── sftp_tmp
│   ├── sql_test.py
│   └── sql_test.pyc
├── qry_exec
│   ├── act_qry_exec_script.py
│   ├── hive_db.logs
│   ├── params.py
│   └── params.pyc
├── sqoop_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sqoop.py
└── test.py
```

Comment: that's not a better practice... at some point you need to import everything into one. say for eg, fl_wtchr_test.py have django 1.8 and if you keep different version on another module. least will override during import 

and module means each py file not a folder

Comment: @MohideenbinMohammed ok i'll update module to subpackage, can u further elaborate your approach please?

Answer (score 0):

A case could be made for creating separate virtual environments for each module; but fundamentally, you want and expect all this code to eventually be able to run without a virtualenv at all. All your modules should be able to run with whatever you install into the top-level virtual environment and so that's what you should primarily be testing against.